# How to set up dnsmasq under linux to use a wildcard domain for local web development with lando/docker?

Tags: linux, dns, docker, dnsmasq

I recently discovered [lando](https://docs.lando.dev/) for local web development, which uses docker in the background. It works great so far, but I have to add every domain for each project manually to my hosts file

`/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   myproject.local.host
127.0.0.1   bs.myproject.local.host
127.0.0.1   bs-admin.myproject.local.host
```

(the `bs.` and `bs-admin.` ones are for [browsersync](https://browsersync.io/))

According to the [lando docs](https://docs.lando.dev/guides/offline-dev.html), it is possible to have a wildcard domain instead of hard coding every domain. Unfortunately are those instructions for MacOS and I am on Arch Linux (Manjaro Gnome 41.3).
I tried to figure it out myself with the help of the page [Arch Wiki: Dnsmasq](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dnsmasq) and other online resources but I couldn't get it to work.

This is what I currently have:

- installed [Dnsmasq](https://archlinux.org/packages/?name=dnsmasq)
   `sudo pacman -S dnsmasq`
- added these lines to the `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` file (everything else in the file was/is commented out):

  ```
  listen-address=::1,127.0.0.1
  expand-hosts
  domain=local.host
  ```
- restart local server `sudo systemctl restart httpd` and `sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq`
- added this line to `~/.lando/config.yml`

  ```
  domain: local.host
  ```
- restart lando `lando poweroff` and `lando start`

However, it does not work:

```
❯ ping http://myproject.local.host:8000/          
ping: http://myproject.local.host:8000/: Name or service not known
❯ ping http://myproject.local.host      
ping: http://myproject.local.host: Name or service not known
❯ ping https://myproject.local.host      
ping: https://myproject.local.host: Name or service not known
```

Adding these lines to `/etc/resolv.conf` didn't help either:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

### Update:

I'm still very confused how `dnsmasq.conf` (`dnsmasq.d`), `etc/hosts`, `etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` interact with each other. But after more reading and trial&error, this is were I am currently:

- added this line to`/etc/dnsmasq.conf` :

  ```
  address=/local.host/127.0.0.1
  ```
- no added lines to `/etc/hosts`
  These lines were in there from [StevenBlack/hosts](https://github.com/StevenBlack/hosts)

  ```
  127.0.0.1 localhost
  127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain
  127.0.0.1 local
  255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
  ::1 localhost
  ::1 ip6-localhost
  ::1 ip6-loopback
  fe80::1%lo0 localhost
  ff00::0 ip6-localnet
  ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
  ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
  ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
  ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
  0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
  ```
- added this line to `/etc/resolv.conf` :

  ```
  nameserver 127.0.0.1
  ```
- ran `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` and `sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq`
- added this line to `~/.lando/config.yml`

  ```
  domain: local.host
  ```
- ran `lando poweroff` and `lando start`

When I test it, I get this:

```
❯ nslookup foo.local.host localhost    
Server:     localhost
Address:    ::1#53

Name:   foo.local.host
Address: 127.0.0.1
```

```
❯ nslookup foo.local.test          
Server:     192.168.2.1
Address:    192.168.2.1#53

** server can't find foo.local.test: NXDOMAIN
```

```
❯ ping foo.local.host       
ping: foo.local.host: Name or service not known
```

`lando start` shows the top two urls in *green* and the bottom two in *red*:

```
APPSERVER URLS  https://localhost:49291                      
                http://localhost:49292                       
                http://myproject.local.host:8000/          
                https://myproject.local.host/
```

Comment: You are missing the most important entry in `dnsmasq.conf`, the one from the guide. Is that intentional?

Comment: `address=/local.host/127.0.0.1`? I tried that before, but that did not work. I assumed the lines I have in the post you do something similar

Comment: What setting is missing/wrong that `nslookup foo.local.host localhost` works, but `nslookup foo.local.host` not?

Answer (score 0):

The `nslookup` tool is a simple case: it always reads /etc/resolv.conf and directly talks to whatever DNS server is found in that file. However, if you have multiple `nameserver` lines in that file, it'll only use one of them, usually the first one.

It's important to keep in mind that additional nameservers in resolv.conf are not "merged". They're only used as fallbacks if the first nameserver is completely unreachable. But if the first server *does* answer "I don't know foo.local.test", **that's the final result** – neither nslookup nor any other program will keep trying other servers in case one of them knows the name.

If your resolv.conf lists the special dnsmasq instance, it *should not* also list your router, or any other DNS server – all your DNS queries should go through dnsmasq (which will forward them to the "real" server if needed).

Systemd-resolved is a separate topic. When it's active, most programs (except for dig/nslookup) will talk to it directly, bypassing the traditional /etc/resolv.conf mechanism. Systemd-resolved itself has two modes: either it reads resolv.conf, or it *provides* resolv.conf.

So if you're using e.g. systemd-resolved and NetworkManager, you should usually change your DNS servers via NetworkManager (connection profile) first, which will then propagate them to systemd-resolved. But if you want to edit resolv.conf manually, first use `ls -l` to make sure it's **not a symlink** to one of systemd-resolved managed files. If needed, remove it and replace with a regular file.

---

Also, these are the only *useful* lines from your /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
```

The rest is entirely useless, even if it happens to come from Debian.

Comment: Sorry, it took my a while to write my answer and then saw your post only after I posted it. Thank you for the clarification, but I do not understand how I should *change DNS servers via NetworkManager (connection profile)*

Comment: The hosts file stuff comes from https://github.com/StevenBlack/hosts/blob/master/updateHostsFile.py (line 1181). I assumed it's there for a reason, so I left it

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trial and error and reading online resources, I found a version that seems to work.

**Disclaimer:** I highly doubt that this is the correct way to do it and there are probably better ways. I also don't know whether all those steps are necessary or what kind of negative implications my settings will have on my system, that I haven't noticed yet.

### Issues before

- NetworkManager was overwriting `/etc/resolv.conf`, so whatever changes I made, where reverted by running `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` [Arch Wiki:NetworkManager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NetworkManager#Unmanaged_/etc/resolv.conf)
- Missing certs in firefox [Lando Docs](https://docs.lando.dev/config/security.html#arch)

### Working version

1. add this line to`/etc/dnsmasq.conf` :

   ```
   address=/local.host/127.0.0.1
   ```
2. leave `/etc/hosts` as is
3. create file `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dns.conf` with content:

   ```
   [main]
   dns=none
   ```
4. add `nameserver 127.0.0.1` at the top of `/etc/resolv.conf`, that looks like this for me:

   ```
   nameserver 127.0.0.1
   nameserver 192.168.2.1
   nameserver fe80::1%enp0s20u2u4
   ```
5. run

   ```shell
   systemctl restart dnsmasq
   systemctl restart NetworkManager
   ```
6. add this line to `~/.lando/config.yml`

   ```
   domain: local.host
   ```
7. run

   ```shell
   lando poweroff
   lando rebuild -y
   ```
8. run

   ```shell
   sudo trust anchor ~/.lando/certs/local.host.pem
   sudo trust anchor ~/.lando/certs/local.host.crt
   ```

### Update

This solution is not persistent, the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` gets overwritten by the NetworkManager, e.g. after restarting
It also causes problems with wifi connections for me.